# UDIM tiles option missing in Blender 3.2

Tags: uv-image-editor

I installed the 3.2 release yesterday and I have come across an issue when working in my character UV's.

Once I've had the UV's unwrapped, I have tried to enlarge the UV tiling space in order to lay out my UV's along several UDIMs, but the option to do so is not in the view tab, where it should be. I have tried with the 3.1 release, and the UDIMs option is there, so I'm not sure whether is an error in the release or a change of place of the option. I have repair the installation of 3.2, as it gave me a warning message the first time, but it continues missing.

The warning in the first installation was something about blender .ink, but I just can't remember the text right now. I pushed "accept" a couple of times and the message went away, so I'm not sure if it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Grids, is inside the Overlays option > Grid X Y

[image]

If you mean the images, then you need to make one and then switch the source to UDIM

[image]